# Chrome scroll behaviour on focus

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have some trouble with focusing elments which are in div with absolute position.
Problem is with absolute div which have large size and it is out of window bounds. When I focus this absolute div, than chrome automaticaly scrolls widow body, but I want to prevent scrolling

I know there is javascript solutions like "document.body.scrollTop = 0;", but I want to find is there css solution for it?

HTML Codde:

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="button" value="make focus" onclick="document.getElementById('innerContainer').focus();" />
    <div tabindex="0" id="innerContainer" /></div>
</div>
```

Css code:

```
 html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden    
}

#innerContainer{
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4000px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
}
#innerContainer:focus{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Link to js fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/3tLbqj5z/2/

[image: Chrome automatically scrolls]

Comment: sorry but m not able to see any scroll bar? can you  please share screenshot?

Comment: In my example scroll visibility is hidden by "overflow: hidden". I attached screenshot, This behaviour appears only on chrome browser